# Establishing myself as an Independent Contractor

Tags: contracting

Need some advice here, as I am not sure where to start.. I have been a contractor for 2 years now and I love the flexibility. Currently, I have agreed to contracts through recruiting agencies and now I am thinking of taking on a new role with a different company.

The new company does not want to go through a recruiting agency however so that means I will need to establish myself as an independent contractor/freelancer. I am super excited about this! I need to know what steps I should make before I start talking about rates and everything else, my main questions are...

**1. Do I need to create an LLC?**

I am mainly wondering how I will handle my taxes.. If I have a business, I can write off my travel time, gas, etc.

**2. How do I clock my time?**

This may be en easy question, I am assuming it varies depending on the client.

**3. Is a blog or online resume the best option?**

This is a question regarding actually making a name for myself. I see blogs related to a certain field, blogs that are more of a business as well as serving as a freelancers display of expertise (The Simple Programmer is an example), and then I see online resumes which do not contain anything bloggy. Just a medium to display ones work.

Comment: Ahh 40 min posting limit.. Thank you @JoeStrazzere

Comment: (3) seems entirely opinion-based, it might be better to remove that from the question as [we're not too fond of opinion-based questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: You should also take a look at [Freelancing.SE](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sole trader or LLC, many prefer sole trader because it's cheaper and you can go it alone easier. But your liability is greater.
2. Clock the hours worked is usual, or charge by the contract as a whole.
3. Why not do both? Your best business if you're starting is going to be word of mouth though, but the more you're out there the better in terms of advertising. After you hit a certain level you don't need to advertise at all assuming you're good at your job.